# How to make Firefox Findbar automatically appear and permanent?

Tags: firefox

I'd like to make the Findbar in Firefox Quantum always visible; ie. I don't want to have to press Ctrl-F or do Main Menu > Edit > Find in This Page.  (Sometimes the web page will override the keyboard shortcuts, and I'm using AutoHotkey GUI automation to search for items in my web page.)

I had found what I thought was the perfect simple way to do this: just modify userChrome.css to tell Firefox to show the Findbar all the time, as follows:

```
#Find#FindToolbar {
    display: -moz-box !important;
}
```

This was from http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=243750&highlight=

However, it doesn't seem to work.  On further examination, the page is from 2005.
Is there a way to do the same with the newer versions of Firefox?  (I'm using v 62.02 -- I'm leery about updating since every little UI tweak means I have to redo my AutoHotkey automation, but I'm willing to update if that will enable a permanent Findbar.)

Thanks

I couldn't find any other site that answered this question.  There were other answers about how to make the Findbar appear in all tabs, and about how it would stay visible forever right after the first time I hit Ctrl-F, but nothing about how to make it appear without having to do anything in the first place.

I tried to ask this in MozillaZine, but when it asked me how many letters there were in Mozilla (and I answered 7), it said that the answer was wrong and I was a spambot.

Comment: Sorry for a typo in the code above.  Instead of "#Find#FindToolbar", it should just say "#FindToolbar".  (And even when thus corrected it doesn't work.)

Comment: To my knowledge this option has been lost in Firefox. There was an add-on for it, findbar tweak, which was lost when Firefox passed to WebExtensions and disabled "legacy" add-ons. You will need a Firefox forked browser that supports both versions of add-ons, such as Pale Moon, to make it work. Does that interest you?

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I had a feeling this might be the case.
But Firefox still uses userChrome.css.  For example, I can still make the Findbar appear at the top or bottom of the screen (but only after I press Ctrl-F).
I'm still holding out hope that there is or will be some declaration or other that makes it permanent.  It would make my GUI automation so much easier.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just [answered a question](https://superuser.com/a/1495397/215736) from someone else detailing how they can inspect Firefox's chrome UI and develop userContent.css for it. Since I still had the Developer stuff within reach, I did a little digging and found the element you want is now called `findbar`. As such, the following code works on Firefox 70:

```
findbar {
  display: -moz-box !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

findbar .close-icon {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Only one caveat: it won't be visible when you first start up Firefox, but after it's been opened, it will stay visible. With a little more work, you might be able to find and fix that caveat too.