# Remove items from Firefox 66's Menu

Tags: firefox

Firefox 66 has the following menu:

[image]

I'll never use many of those items and they add visual noise which I don't like.

Is there an easy way to remove some of the items?  For example: content blocking, zoom, edit, sign into sync, open file..., and find in this page.

Answer (score 0):

So, developing a solution to this comes in two parts.

The first part is enabling the [Developer Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) so you can analyze the DOM of the browser itself (aka the chrome). Using this is much like using the regular web developer tools for web pages.

The second part is writing the userChrome.css and enabling it on your profile. userChrome is kind-of deprecated now, but you can still make it work on Firefox 69+ by [following this guide](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html).

At a quick glance, I can see that the main Firefox menu has an ID of `#appMenu-mainView` so you should start your search for menu items there. As a quick example, the following userChrome.css would hide the 'Open in Private Window' menu item:

```
#appMenu-private-window-button {display: none}
```

If you have experience with CSS, then the rest is easy!