# Keep Firefox find bar and search term open on all tabs, and persisting on session restart

Tags: firefox, browser, search, tabs

I regularly across many search tabs (and using [multiple tab rows](https://github.com/Izheil/Quantum-Nox-Firefox-Dark-Full-Theme/releases) on a 23" desktop monitor then I have many) for a certain text, such as in doing research, and want the findbar persisting open on all tabs after a restart, as well as in new tabs,  and with the same search string being visible (the old Findbar ext. for legacy FF enabled that).  Having to hit F3 or ctrl+f for each tab, and doing so even when a session with the same tabs are loaded, adds time and reduces efficiency.

Why? When researching an issue or shopping, I typically open multiple search results, and in which I am looking for one word or phrase, and thus having the find bar already visible and with the search term is more efficient.

Note that backslash / will open the "QuickFind" bar, but does not consistently work nor keep the same search term.   Perhaps what is needed is someway to trigger F3 on every tab load. Note that there have been [complaints](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=920031) about the behavior of the Findbar under [bug reports](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=537013).

This has been asked before and with the latest explanation (by harrymc)  being that "The findbar is no longer part of the Firefox window, so cannot be customized by CSS. It's now built-into the Firefox GUI."

MC10's thus [responded](https://superuser.com/a/1756335/368970)  "You can use this in your `userChrome.css`:"

```
findbar[hidden] {
    display: -moz-box !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 150ms !important;
}
```

However, I added this to my userChrome.css on FF 109 and have userprof set to true in `about:config`, yet while the findfbar will remain open on a page for a while once you opened it on that page, yet FF does that anyway (usually, though not on all pages), versus the findbar remaining/persisting open on all tabs and with the same search string being visible to look up. As the old Findbar extension did. If ctrl+f could somehow be triggered automatically, then this would provide the desired function.

Comment: Doesn't Ctrl+F or Ctrl+G keep the search item?

Comment: Yes, or F3 (far better),  and which is better than  Chromium-based Vivaldi, in which it is assumed users would not be searching for the same words across tabs. However,  you still need  to hit F3 to make the search in page visible.

Answer (score 0):

The findbar is a new element on each page. You could trigger it to open automatically using custom scripts (userChrome.js) but it would not persist your search string.

You can use this add-on instead to search across all tabs: [Search all Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/search-all-tabs/)

Comment: Thanks. I already have Search multi tabs (I tried  Search all Tabs but it never shows up) which does search content (check Regular expression for most results), showing a list of occurrences in tabs in a left pane, and is helpful,  but that is not as efficient as what I am looking for.

I already have a custom userChrome but do you know the script that would result in the findbar being on every page by default, even if it does not show the search term? Thanks again.